# How do I make my HTML text color an animated gradient with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I've got a CSS gradient and an `h1` element. I want to set the text color to the gradient but it just makes it the background. I've tried an inherit but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```css
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">Welcome To <span class="gradient"><b>Mnazz Suite</b></span></h1>
```

Comment: Look up background-clip: text

Comment: @AHaworth `background-clip` won't work here, but the more modern `-webkit-background-clip` will. See my answer.

Comment: @snbs see https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip it’s not a question of ‘more modern’ it’s a question of where ‘here’ is ie whether the browser requires the prefix or not. That’s why I suggested OP searched for background-clip - places like MDN will tell you if you need a prefix or not.

Comment: @SNBS `-webkit-background-clip` is _NOT_ more modern; it is the prefixed version, which was added before the proprtt was standardized enough to be included unprefixed.

Answer (score -2):

You need WebKit for that. Add this style to `.gradient`:

```css
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Also add `background-clip` and `text-fill-color` without WebKit for compatibility.

**Note that just `background-clip` without WebKit won't work here**, it'll only animate the background.

*UPDATE*: see [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SNBSLibs/pen/KKrRwzY).

Comment: Some browsers may need the prefix, some browsers don’t (at this point in time).

Comment: You do _NOT_ need a WebKit browser for this. E.g., Firefox supports the unprefixed property. If you mean the prefixed variant of the property, that is also mo strictly true; it depends on your browser's support.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Yes you do. It'll only animate the background without WebKit. Without prefix it doesn't work in Firefox either.

Comment: Are you referring to the browser or property prefix?

Comment: Add your code example to this answer, not a link to a codepen. Much more helpful to future visitors. Also, FireFox does 100% support the unprefixed property when applied to text. Checkout out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Comment: I wanted future visitors to be able to remove prefix and see changes.

Comment: So what if your Codepen link is removed? Future visitors won't get to try anything. Add two examples in a snippet then.

Comment: Works fine in Safari iOS without the prefix (of course text-fill doesn’t, but color:transparent is fine for this). How about editing your answer so it is correct?

Comment: But the OP wants the code to work in other browsers as well.

Comment: You use _both_ properties. Look at the example on the previously linked MDN page, for example.

Comment: Oh yes, they should be also added for compatibility. Edited my answer.